# basic reactjs, how to get REST data and render it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a basic rect component and I already figured out how to get data from a protected rest api, however I am not sure how to render it in the component and how to call that function, or in which lifecycle I should call the function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LayoutContentWrapper from '../components/utility/layoutWrapper';
import LayoutContent from '../components/utility/layoutContent';
var q = require('q');

var Adal = require('../adal-webapi/adal-request');

function getValues() {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    Adal.adalRequest({
      url: 'https://abc.azurewebsites.net/api/values'
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }, function(err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }

export default class extends Component {



  render() {
    return (
      <LayoutContentWrapper style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
        <LayoutContent>
          <h1>Test Page</h1>
        </LayoutContent>
      </LayoutContentWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Easiest way is to put `getValues` inside the class. Then make a variable in `this.state` that you can assign the data you get from your API. Just render that `this.state` variable

Comment: Once you fetch your data from the server, you have to set it to state and then you can display it in your view. `return` block

Comment: I don't think putting `getValues` into the component is necessary, if anything, I'd abstract it through a non-react class that only handles react requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifecycle method you choose to fetch the data in will largely depend on whether or not you need to update the data at any point and re-render, or whether that data depends on any props passed to the component.

Your example looks as though it is a one time API call that doesn't depend on any props, so placing it in the constructor would be valid.

I would move the getValues code to within the class, and do something like this. Note: I've used async/await, but you could use promise callbacks if you prefer.

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
        this.fetchData();
    }

    async fetchData() {
        try {
            const data = await this.getValues();
            !this.isCancelled && this.setState({ data });
        } catch(error) {
            // Handle accordingly
        }
    }

    getValues() { 
        // Your API calling code
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.isCancelled = true;
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        return (
            <ul>
                {data && data.map(item => (
                    <li>{item.name}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

If you needed to fetch the data again at any point, you might use one of the other lifecycle hooks to listen for prop changes, and call the `fetchData` method again.

Note the inclusion of a failsafe for the component un-mounting before the async call has finished, preventing React from throwing an error about setting state in an unmounted component.

Comment: Good call on cancelling request on unmount

Answer (score 1):

something like this...

```
export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // initialize myData to prevent render from running map on undefined
    this.state = {myData: []};
  }

  // use componentDidMount lifecycle method to call function
  componentDidMount() {
    // call your function here, and on promise execute `setState` callback
    getValues()
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({myData: data})
      }
  }

  render() {
    // create a list
    const items = this.state.myData.map((datum) => {
      return <LayoutContent>
        <h1>{datum}</h1>
      </LayoutContent>
   });

    // return with the list
    return (
      <LayoutContentWrapper style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
        {items}
      </LayoutContentWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think running `getValues` in a `componentDidMount` is a better option. Also, you don't need to hold a temporary assignment of context when you use an arrow function. You can keep it as `this.setState`

Comment: updated the code. The convention **is** to use `componentDidMount` as it makes component extension more straight forward.

Comment: Yes I am aware, I just didn't want to come off as a dick :P. `componentDidMount` ensures `render` has already been run, and since `setState` is async, the sequence of events can get fumbled around when it's run in the `constructor`.

Comment: that part of the comment wasn't meant for you, just wanted to clarify the reason for updating